# How to call a function in a function onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

At first I want to apologize for my bad English.

I am making tic tac toe in JavaScript, but the reloading of the game isn't working for me. I have made a button like this: `<button onclick="restart()"> Opnieuw! </button>` My script looks like this:

```
function Canvas(){

    /* other functions */

    function restart(){

    }
}
```

When I try to click the button I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: restart is not defined [chrome]

I need to place the restart function in my canvas function to chance the value's. So does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Here is my whole code (run the snippet in full page to actualy make the game work):

```js
 /*                          
   
   ---------------------------
    Door Thomas Pereira,
    6-5-2015, 14:00, NL    
   ---------------------------       
           
           
             */

 function Canvas() {
   var ctx = document.getElementById('game').getContext('2d');
   var cw = ctx.canvas.width,
     ch = ctx.canvas.height;
   var snelheid = 1;
   var linewidth = 6;
   var fSmall = 0.3;
   var fout = -1;
   var apl = {};
   apl.speak = function(line) {
     console.log(line);
   };





   function tekenkruis(x, y, w, h) {
     ctx.beginPath();
     x += w * (fSmall * 0.5);
     y += h * (fSmall * 0.5);
     w -= w * fSmall;
     h -= h * fSmall;
     ctx.moveTo(x, y);
     ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h);
     ctx.moveTo(x + w, y);
     ctx.lineTo(x, y + h);
     ctx.lineWidth = linewidth;
     ctx.stroke();
   }

   function tekencirkel(x, y, w, h) {
     ctx.beginPath();
     x += w * (fSmall * 0.5);
     y += h * (fSmall * 0.5);
     w -= w * fSmall;
     h -= h * fSmall;
     ctx.arc(x + (w * 0.5), y + (h * 0.5), w * 0.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
     ctx.lineWidth = linewidth;
     ctx.stroke();
   }

   function random(min, max, t, niet) {
     var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
     if (t) {
       for (var i = "fout"; i == even_odd(num, t, niet); i) {
         var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
       }
       return num;
     } else {
       return num;
     }
   }

   function even_odd(num, t, niet) {
     if (num % 2 == 0 && t == "even" && num != niet || num % 2 == 1 && t == "odd" && num != niet) {
       return num;
     } else {
       return "fout";
     }
   }

   function checkbestaan(z) {
     var q = invullen.plaatsen[z];
     if (q.kruis != "on" && q.cirkel != "on") {
       return z;
     } else {
       return "fout"
     }
   }


   /*  Main Functions  */


   function background() {
     this.w = cw, this.h = ch, this.x = 0, this.y = 0, this.color = "#F4F4F5";
     this.draw = function() {
       //draw
       ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
       ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);

       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.moveTo(0, (1 / 3) * ch);
       ctx.lineTo(cw, (1 / 3) * ch);
       ctx.moveTo(0, (2 / 3) * ch);
       ctx.lineTo(cw, (2 / 3) * ch);
       ctx.moveTo((1 / 3) * cw, 0);
       ctx.lineTo((1 / 3) * cw, ch);
       ctx.moveTo((2 / 3) * cw, 0);
       ctx.lineTo((2 / 3) * cw, ch);
       ctx.lineWidth = linewidth;
       ctx.stroke();
     }
   }

   function invullen() {
     this.x = fout;
     this.y = fout;
     this.call = "on";
     this.tel = 0;
     this.kansplaatsen = [];
     this.tel2 = 0;
     this.plaatsen = [{
       "naam": 1,
       "x": 0,
       "y": 0,
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": 2,
       "x": cw * (1 / 3),
       "y": 0,
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": 3,
       "x": cw * (2 / 3),
       "y": 0,
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": 8,
       "x": 0,
       "y": ch * (1 / 3),
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": "fout",
       "x": cw * (1 / 3),
       "y": ch * (1 / 3),
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": 4,
       "x": cw * (2 / 3),
       "y": ch * (1 / 3),
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": 7,
       "x": 0,
       "y": ch * (2 / 3),
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": 6,
       "x": cw * (1 / 3),
       "y": ch * (2 / 3),
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": 5,
       "x": cw * (2 / 3),
       "y": ch * (2 / 3),
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, ];
     this.win = [{
       "plek1": 0,
       "plek2": 1,
       "plek3": 2
     }, {
       "plek1": 3,
       "plek2": 4,
       "plek3": 5
     }, {
       "plek1": 6,
       "plek2": 7,
       "plek3": 8
     }, {
       "plek1": 0,
       "plek2": 3,
       "plek3": 6
     }, {
       "plek1": 1,
       "plek2": 4,
       "plek3": 7
     }, {
       "plek1": 2,
       "plek2": 5,
       "plek3": 8
     }, {
       "plek1": 0,
       "plek2": 4,
       "plek3": 8
     }, {
       "plek1": 2,
       "plek2": 4,
       "plek3": 6
     }, ];
     this.wandplaatsen = [{
       "plek": "undefined"
     }, {
       "plek": 0
     }, {
       "plek": 1
     }, {
       "plek": 2
     }, {
       "plek": 5
     }, {
       "plek": 8
     }, {
       "plek": 7
     }, {
       "plek": 6
     }, {
       "plek": 3
     }, ];
     this.draw = function() {
       //check of er in een vak geklikt is
       for (var i = 0; i < this.plaatsen.length; i++) {
         var k = this.plaatsen[i]
         if (this.x >= k.x && this.x <= k.x + k.w && this.y >= k.y && this.y <= k.y + k.h && k.cirkel != "on" && k.kruis != "on") {
           k.kruis = "on";
           this.call = "on";
           this.stap = i;
         }
       }
       this.x = fout;
       this.y = fout; //schakel klik uit

       //als er geklikt is de PC

       if (this.call == "on") {
         this.tel++

           this.checklaatste = this.laatste;
         loop1:
           for (var i = 1; i == 1; i) {
             loop2: for (var i = 1; i < this.wandplaatsen.length; i++) {
               var k = this.wandplaatsen[i];
               if (i + 1 > 8) {
                 var de = i + 1 - 8;
               } else {
                 var de = i + 1;
               };
               var d = this.wandplaatsen[de];
               if (i - 1 < 1) {
                 var ce = i - 1 + 8;
               } else {
                 var ce = i - 1;
               };
               var c = this.wandplaatsen[ce];
               if (i + 2 > 8) {
                 var re = i + 2 - 8;
               } else {
                 var re = i + 2;
               };
               var r = this.wandplaatsen[re];
               if (i - 2 < 1) {
                 var qe = i - 2 + 8;
               } else {
                 var qe = i - 2;
               };
               var q = this.wandplaatsen[qe];
               if (i + 4 > 8) {
                 var ye = i + 4 - 8
               } else {
                 var ye = i + 4
               };
               var y = this.wandplaatsen[ye];
               if (i - 4 < 1) {
                 var we = i - 4 + 8
               } else {
                 var we = i - 4
               };
               var w = this.wandplaatsen[we];
               apl.speak("Niewe i is: " + i + "  -  " + this.plaatsen[k.plek].cirkel);
               if (this.plaatsen[k.plek].cirkel == "on") {
                 if (i % 2 == 1) {
                   apl.speak("door " + i);
                   if (this.plaatsen[d.plek].cirkel == "on") {
                     if (i + 2 > 8) {
                       var g = i + 2 - 8;
                     } else {
                       var g = i + 2;
                     };
                     apl.speak("hier zijn we d: " + checkbestaan(this.wandplaatsen[g].plek));
                     if (checkbestaan(this.wandplaatsen[g].plek) != "fout") {
                       this.plaatsen[this.wandplaatsen[g].plek].cirkel = "on";
                       this.laatste = this.wandplaatsen[g].plek;
                       this.call = "off";
                       break loop1;
                     };
                   }
                   if (this.plaatsen[c.plek].cirkel == "on") {
                     if (i - 2 < 1) {
                       var ge = i - 2 + 8;
                     } else {
                       var ge = i - 2;
                     };
                     apl.speak("hier zijn we c: " + checkbestaan(this.wandplaatsen[ge].plek));
                     if (checkbestaan(this.wandplaatsen[ge].plek) != "fout") {
                       apl.speak("hier zijn we c: done: " + i);
                       this.plaatsen[this.wandplaatsen[ge].plek].cirkel = "on";
                       this.laatste = this.wandplaatsen[ge].plek;
                       this.call = "off";
                       break loop1;
                     };
                   }
                   if (this.plaatsen[r.plek].cirkel == "on") {
                     if (i + 1 > 8) {
                       var ge = i + 1 - 8;
                     } else {
                       var ge = i + 1;
                     };
                     apl.speak("hier zijn we r: " + checkbestaan(this.wandplaatsen[ge].plek));
                     if (checkbestaan(this.wandplaatsen[ge].plek) != "fout") {
                       this.plaatsen[this.wandplaatsen[ge].plek].cirkel = "on";
                       this.laatste = this.wandplaatsen[ge].plek;
                       this.call = "off";
                       break loop1;
                     };
                   }
                   if (this.plaatsen[q.plek].cirkel == "on") {
                     if (i - 1 < 1) {
                       var ge = i - 1 + 8;
                     } else {
                       var ge = i - 1;
                     };
                     /*apl.speak("hier zijn we q: "+checkbestaan(this.wandplaatsen[ge].plek));*/
                     if (checkbestaan(this.wandplaatsen[ge].plek) != "fout") {
                       this.plaatsen[this.wandplaatsen[ge].plek].cirkel = "on";
                       this.laatste = this.wandplaatsen[ge].plek;
                       this.call = "off";
                       break loop1;
                     };
                   }
                   if (this.plaatsen[w.plek].cirkel == "on") {
                     var g = 4;
                     apl.speak("hier zijn we wr: " + checkbestaan(g));
                     if (checkbestaan(g) != "fout") {
                       this.plaatsen[g].cirkel = "on";
                       this.laatste = g;
                       this.call = "off";
                       break loop1;
                     };
                   }
                   if (this.plaatsen[y.plek].cirkel == "on") {
                     var g = 4;
                     apl.speak("hier zijn we yr: " + checkbestaan(g));
                     if (checkbestaan(g) != "fout") {
                       this.plaatsen[g].cirkel = "on";
                       this.laatste = g;
                       this.call = "off";
                       break loop1;
                     };
                   }
                 }

                 /* if( i % 2 == 0 ){
         apl.speak("door even"+ i);
         if( this.plaatsen[w.plek].cirkel == "on" && this.call == "on" ){
          if( i-4 < 1 ){ var g = 8-Math.abs(i-4); } else { var g = i-4; };
          apl.speak("hier zijn we w: "+checkbestaan(this.wandplaatsen[g].plek));
          if( checkbestaan(this.wandplaatsen[g].plek) != "fout" ){
           this.plaatsen[this.wandplaatsen[g].plek].cirkel = "on";
           this.laatste = this.wandplaatsen[g].plek;
           this.call = "off";
          };
         } 
         if( this.plaatsen[y.plek].cirkel == "on" && this.call == "on" ){
          if( i+4 > 8 ){ var g = i+4-8; } else { var g = i+4; };
          apl.speak("hier zijn we y: "+checkbestaan(this.wandplaatsen[g].plek));
          if( checkbestaan(this.wandplaatsen[g].plek) != "fout" ){
           this.plaatsen[this.wandplaatsen[g].plek].cirkel = "on";
           this.laatste = this.wandplaatsen[g].plek;
           this.call = "off";
          };
         }
        
        } */
               }
             }

               for (var i = 1; i < this.wandplaatsen.length; i++) {
               var k = this.wandplaatsen[i];
               if (i - 4 < 1) {
                 var we = i - 4 + 8
               } else {
                 var we = i - 4
               };
               var w = this.wandplaatsen[we];

               if (this.plaatsen[k.plek].kruis == "on" && i % 2 == 0) {
                 apl.speak("door even : " + i)
                 if (this.plaatsen[4].kruis == "on") {
                   apl.speak("hier zijn we 4: " + checkbestaan(w.plek));
                   if (checkbestaan(w.plek) != "fout") {
                     this.plaatsen[w.plek].cirkel = "on";
                     this.laatste = w.plek;
                     this.call = "off";
                     break loop1;
                   }
                 }
                 if (this.plaatsen[w.plek].kruis == "on") {
                   apl.speak("hier zijn we w.plek: " + checkbestaan(4));
                   if (checkbestaan(4) != "fout") {
                     this.plaatsen[4].cirkel = "on";
                     this.laatste = 4;
                     this.call = "off";
                     break loop1;
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
             break loop1;
           }

         apl.speak("--------------------------");

         if (this.checklaatste != this.laatste) {
           this.call = "off"
         };

         if (this.tel == 1 && this.call == "on") {
           this.stap1 = random(0, 8, "even", 4);
           for (var i = "fout"; i == checkbestaan(this.stap1); i) {
             this.stap1 = random(0, 8, "even", 4);
           };
           this.plaatsen[this.stap1].cirkel = "on";
           this.call = "off";
           this.laatste = this.stap1;
         } else if (this.tel == 2 && this.call == "on") {
           var g = this.plaatsen[this.stap1].naam + 4;
           if (g > 8) {
             var g = g - 8;
           }
           var c = this.plaatsen[this.stap1].naam + 1;
           var d = this.plaatsen[this.stap1].naam - 1;
           if (d > 8) {
             var d = d - 8;
           }
           if (this.stap != 4 || checkbestaan(this.wandplaatsen[g].plek) == "fout") {
             this.stap2 = random(0, 8, "even", 4)
             for (var i = "fout"; i == checkbestaan(this.stap2); i) {
               this.stap2 = random(0, 8, "even", 4)
             };
           } else {
             this.stap2 = this.wandplaatsen[g].plek;
           }
           this.plaatsen[this.stap2].cirkel = "on";
           this.call = "off";
           this.laatste = this.stap2;
         } else if (this.tel == 3 && this.call == "on") {
           this.stap3 = random(0, 8, "even", 4)
           for (var i = "fout"; i == checkbestaan(this.stap3); i) {
             this.stap3 = random(0, 8, "even", 4)
             this.tel2++;
             if (this.tel2 > 1000) {
               this.tel2 = 0;
               this.stap3 = random(0, 8);
               for (var i = "fout"; i == checkbestaan(this.stap3); i) {
                 this.stap3 = random(0, 8);
               };
             };
           };
           this.plaatsen[this.stap3].cirkel = "on";
           this.call = "off";
           this.laatste = this.stap3;
         } else if (this.tel == 4 && this.call == "on") {
           this.stap4 = random(0, 8, "even", 4)
           for (var i = "fout"; i == checkbestaan(this.stap4); i) {
             this.stap4 = random(0, 8, "even", 4);
             this.tel2++;
             if (this.tel2 > 1000) {
               this.tel2 = 0;
               this.stap4 = random(0, 8);
               for (var i = "fout"; i == checkbestaan(this.stap4); i) {
                 this.stap4 = random(0, 8);
               };
             };
           }
           this.plaatsen[this.stap4].cirkel = "on";
           this.call = "off";
           this.laatste = this.stap4;
         } else if (this.call == "on") {
           var q = random(0, 8);
           for (var i = "fout"; i == checkbestaan(q); i) {
             var q = random(0, 8);
           };
           this.plaatsen[q].cirkel = "on"
           this.call = "off";
           this.laatste = q;
         }
       }

       //teken
       for (var i = 0; i < this.plaatsen.length; i++) {
         var k = this.plaatsen[i];
         if (k.kruis == "on") {
           tekenkruis(k.x, k.y, k.w, k.h)
         }
       }
       for (var i = 0; i < this.plaatsen.length; i++) {
         var k = this.plaatsen[i];
         if (k.cirkel == "on") {
           tekencirkel(k.x, k.y, k.w, k.h)
         };
       }
     }
   }

   function checkwin() {
     this.done = "false"
     this.draw = function() {
       for (var i = 0; i < invullen.win.length; i++) {
         if (invullen.plaatsen[invullen.win[i].plek1].kruis == "on" && invullen.plaatsen[invullen.win[i].plek2].kruis == "on" && invullen.plaatsen[invullen.win[i].plek3].kruis == "on") {
           invullen.plaatsen[invullen.laatste].cirkel = "off";
           for (var i = 0; i < invullen.plaatsen.length; i++) {
             var k = invullen.plaatsen[i];
             if (k.cirkel == "on") {
               tekencirkel(k.x, k.y, k.w, k.h)
             };
           }
           ctx.font = "17px Arial";
           ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
           ctx.fillStyle = "black";
           var text = " Jij hebt gewonnen!!"
           ctx.fillText(text, 20, 20);
           clearInterval(animateInterval);
           this.done = "true"
         }
       }
       for (var i = 0; i < invullen.win.length; i++) {
         if (this.done != "true" && invullen.plaatsen[invullen.win[i].plek1].cirkel == "on" && invullen.plaatsen[invullen.win[i].plek2].cirkel == "on" && invullen.plaatsen[invullen.win[i].plek3].cirkel == "on") {
           ctx.font = "17px Arial";
           ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
           ctx.fillStyle = "black";
           var text = "De PC heeft gewonnen, jammer"
           ctx.fillText(text, 20, 20);
           clearInterval(animateInterval);
         }
       }
     }
   }

   var background = new background();
   var invullen = new invullen();
   var checkwin = new checkwin();

   function draw() {
     ctx.save();
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);

     //draw
     background.draw();
     invullen.draw();
     checkwin.draw();

     ctx.restore();
   }

   var animateInterval = setInterval(draw, snelheid);

   ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
     invullen.x = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
     invullen.y = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
   });

   function restart() {
     background.w = cw, background.h = ch, background.x = 0, background.y = 0, background.color = "#F4F4F5";
     invullen.x = fout;
     invullen.y = fout;
     invullen.call = "on";
     invullen.tel = 0;
     invullen.kansplaatsen = [];
     invullen.tel2 = 0;
     invullen.plaatsen = [{
       "naam": 1,
       "x": 0,
       "y": 0,
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": 2,
       "x": cw * (1 / 3),
       "y": 0,
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": 3,
       "x": cw * (2 / 3),
       "y": 0,
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": 8,
       "x": 0,
       "y": ch * (1 / 3),
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": "fout",
       "x": cw * (1 / 3),
       "y": ch * (1 / 3),
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": 4,
       "x": cw * (2 / 3),
       "y": ch * (1 / 3),
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": 7,
       "x": 0,
       "y": ch * (2 / 3),
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": 6,
       "x": cw * (1 / 3),
       "y": ch * (2 / 3),
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, {
       "naam": 5,
       "x": cw * (2 / 3),
       "y": ch * (2 / 3),
       "w": cw * (1 / 3),
       "h": ch * (1 / 3),
       "kruis": "off",
       "cirkel": "off"
     }, ];
     invullen.win = [{
       "plek1": 0,
       "plek2": 1,
       "plek3": 2
     }, {
       "plek1": 3,
       "plek2": 4,
       "plek3": 5
     }, {
       "plek1": 6,
       "plek2": 7,
       "plek3": 8
     }, {
       "plek1": 0,
       "plek2": 3,
       "plek3": 6
     }, {
       "plek1": 1,
       "plek2": 4,
       "plek3": 7
     }, {
       "plek1": 2,
       "plek2": 5,
       "plek3": 8
     }, {
       "plek1": 0,
       "plek2": 4,
       "plek3": 8
     }, {
       "plek1": 2,
       "plek2": 4,
       "plek3": 6
     }, ];
     invullen.wandplaatsen = [{
       "plek": "undefined"
     }, {
       "plek": 0
     }, {
       "plek": 1
     }, {
       "plek": 2
     }, {
       "plek": 5
     }, {
       "plek": 8
     }, {
       "plek": 7
     }, {
       "plek": 6
     }, {
       "plek": 3
     }, ];
     checkwin.done = "false"
   }

 };





 window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
   Canvas();
 });
```

```css
#game {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="game" width="500px" height="500px">
  Please get a new browser!
</canvas>
<button onclick="restart()">Opnieuw!</button>
```

Comment: canvas.addEventListener('click', function( e ) {  if( .. ) { // do something }  }, false); a rough soultion, In the function, check for attributes like #id of button.

Comment: Does that suits your requirement http://jsfiddle.net/kx17cnsL/

Comment: not working for me, but thnx @Rakesh_Kumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
function Canvas(){

    /* other functions */

    this.restart = function(){

    }
}
```

then:

```
var canvas = new Canvas();
button.onclick = function() {
    canvas.restart();
}
```

By this way, you can call the function into the context canvas. Because, `this.restart` is now a method belongs to `Canvas`

Comment: This Will Work, The Problem was your restart() click function was out of scope. It was part of your Canvas() object. By placing it in global scope like Radonirina suggested. The Button can find and access it when clicked.

Answer (score 2):

you must declare `restart` in the global context to access it from the button.

if you must declare it `Canvas` function replace

```
function replace(){
   //your code
}
```

to this without `var`:

```
restart = function(){
   //your same code
}
```

this will access local variables in `canvas` function and declare it globally.